# Finding new pages on a website

Tags: html, web-crawler

I'm wanting to know how to find newly created pages for a specific website.

The more info I can get, the better. Info such as; date created, etc.

**So for example**: I'd like to be able to find out every new page that shirtoid.com uploads/creates.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a software that does as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

They have an [RSS feed](http://shirtoid.com/feed/) which you can follow. You can use an rss reader to get updates automatically. Or if you want to use the data inside some software ur trying to develop then I'm sure there is a library for working with RSS feeds.